# h2o and coxph ERRR on field: _train: Training data must have at least 2 features (incl. response)

Tags: r, h2o

I am trying to build a model of Cox Proportional Hazard with h2o. In fact a I have succesfully built a model using deeplearning about survival in gastric cancer dataset. When trying to do it with h2o.coxph, I always get "ERRR on field: _train: Training data must have at least 2 features (incl. response)". I have checked that my data train frame has the column of "event/response" (Have tried with factor/numeric/integer with same results). Also I have tried with an invented  10 observations dataset which include "start column (all zeros), stop colum (random>0), event column (random (0,1)) and a predictor (eg:age (random>20), with the same results.

But when I import the data (csv file) that under the "help section" is suggested, and check the datatype of the start,stop and event column, are similar to those I have, but in this case I can build the model. I don't know which the problem is.

Any suggestions??

This is my code:

```
h2o.init()

#Load data into the cluster
datos_h2o<-as.h2o(prueba_2)

#Build the model
modelo_coxph <- h2o.coxph(x = "edad", training_frame = datos_h2o,
                         event_column = "event",
                         start_column= "inicio",
                         stop_column = "final"
                        )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved. If I omit the "start column" it works. I don't know why, cause thought that this columns represents the beginning time of the observations, which means it could have zero values, but it can't.